# Substraction in assembly 8086 sets wrong flags

Tags: assembly, binary, cpu, cpu-registers, x86-16

I am trying to do a simple math calculation. Here is my code:

```
mov al, 128
sub al, -128
```

I need to know which flags are set by the sub instruction. My calculations are like this. Starting with the idea that `sub` is the same as `+(- your number)`. Starting from *mov, al 128*, we have this:

Here is `AL`:

```
128 = 0x80 = 1000 0000b
```

The second step, is to get `-128`, which is the 2nd complement of 128, in other words:

```
 128 = 1000 0000b
-128 = 0111 1111b (1st complement) + 1 = 1000 0000b
```

So ... we got the same number ... now we have to add them, because that's what sub is doing, instead of real subtraction, is adding with the negative number.

The final result would be:

```
 1000 0000b +
 1000 0000b
 ----------
10000 0000b
```

This indicated that the following flags are set: **CF** (there is a carry), **ZF** (0 in AL), and **PF** (even number of 1's from d0 to d3).

If I run the same code, which is again:

```
mov al, 128
sub al, -128
```

It will set only the **ZF** and **PF**, but **no CF**. The question is why ?
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**the idea that sub is the same as +(- your number).**

To the CPU this is not true. Your first number and second number are equal. The fact that you as a human understand that the second number is a negative one does not make a difference to the processor. It will subtract 2 equal numbers and so no borrow is needed.

Comment: ok, but the instruction is sub al, -128, how will the CPU understand this ? He's doing it negative, and gets that basically it's the same number, and just does 128 - 128 = 0, that's it ? This means that sub is the same as + (-number) is not true, not even for humans.

Comment: It is your assembler that translates the value -128 to the byte content 0x10000000. The CPU afterwards only sees 2 equal numbers. Your *basic idea* does work for humans because we are not limited to (in this case) 8 bits of data.

Comment: @user1812076 The CPU is doing, what you wrote down in your question. It will create the 2's complement and add the numbers. This operation will create a carry, but the carry will be inversed/negated, because the subtraction op-code is used. You made it a bit more complicated by choosing "128" in your example, which is already out of the range for 2k in 8 Bit: -128 =< x =< 127

Answer (score 0):

When you add two numbers, the carry flag is set when a carry out of the most significant takes place. BUT when you subtract two numbers the carry flag is reversed in x86. In your example you had a carry when doing the subtraction and because of that the cf was not set.

The cpu is doing this,  because when doing subtraction it uses the carry flag as a borrow flag. And when you do subtraction by adding with 2s complement, you have no borrow when a carry out of the most significant bit takes places. And the other way around: no carry out of msb means that a borrow happened, thus x86 cpu sets the cf = 1. Sounds a bit strange at first, but is quite useful for subtracting with borrow op code for example: sbb

Comment: no need to downvote the truth. At least comment why. :P